# Deploying Windows XP via Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2008 to workstations with SATA

Tags: windows-xp, wds

I'm trying to deploy a custom XP WIM image to some new Lenovo laptops using MDT2008.  I've built the machines using the Lenovo-supplied XP downgrade utility, added some custom applications which I want to be pre-installed and customised a SYSPREP.INF file and run sysprep to reseal the machine.  The sysprep.inf tells it to do a full hardware detect during minisetup and the drivers for the SATA controller are definitely installed prior to the sysprep.

I then image the machine by booting to the MDT WinPE environment, mapping a drive to the deployment share and creating a WIM image using ImageX.

All of the drivers for this model of laptop are in the MDT driver repository

The target machine is then PXE booted to the MDT WinPE environment via the WDS server (same machine as MDT is installed on) and the image is copied across including the driver injection scripts.  The machine then reboots and all seems well as it comes up, goes through the mini setup and then you can use the machine successfully.  When you reboot the workstation, it then bluescreens with an Inaccessible Boot Device message and it appears not to have loaded the SATA drivers into XP.

All I can figure is that there is a MININT folder prior to the reboot which is no longer there afterward so I am guessing that the initial boot is done from MININT which has the relevant drivers but that the full reboot boots from WINDOWS which doesn't.

I'm struggling to find any good information on deploying XP using MDT2008 - particularly for devices which need SATA support.  Can anyone help or point me in the right direction as I'm sure I'm just missing a step somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Check for AHCI in the BIOS, and if present switch it to legacy/SATA/whatever the alternative is.

Comment: Yeah tried both modes but it doesn't seem to make much difference.  Weird thing is that XP works fine in non-legacy mode before imaging